# Why can a isolated spherical conductor act as a capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

So, a while ago I learned that a spherical isolated conductor can act as a capacitor now my question is how? I mean, a capacitor usually requires two plates to hold charge but in this case there's just one charged conductor. So how is it really storing energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sphere is assumed to be at infinity,a sphere of infinite radii
So basically it's just your normal capacitor

Comment: Why is this a special property of a sphere? Why can’t an isolated plate or cylinder have a capacitance associated with it?

Comment: @Roy: Different shapes work too. Spheres are just easier to do the math for.